# Can't load jquery in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
 "content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["http://code.jquery.com/*"],
  "js": ["jquery.js", "popup.html"]
}
]
```

But when I'm reloading the extension, I get an error that the extension could not load jquery.js.What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the cause, but you're **not** fetching `http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js` or something similar. You need to put `jquery.js` in your extension's directory. Are you sure you are doing so?

Comment: You mean a blank file called jquery.js? It's working I don't get any erros now, but I stil can't use jquery code.. in my popup.html

Comment: Ah now I have understood what you told me, please write you comment as an answer so I can accept it.Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you think you're using `http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js`, but that's not the case. Your current setup meeans: on any page on `http://code.jquery.com`, load `index.html` and `jquery.js`.

Those files should be saved as part of your extension. `jquery.js` at least - I don't think you want `popup.html` to be part of your content script - it is not a JavaScript file, and an extension's popup is something completely different than a content script.